# Symfony 4 Form file upload field does not show selected filename with Bootstrap 4 theme

Tags: file-upload, bootstrap-4, symfony4

Using Symfony 4.2.5, I made a Form with a FileType file upload field as described at [upload file](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html).  I used the Bootstrap 4 theme as described at [form_themes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html) and [bootstrap4](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/bootstrap4.html).

config/packages/twig.yaml contains:

```
twig:
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig']
```

When I load the web page and select a file to upload, the FileType field shows a blank filename:
[image: before]

I found this issue was documented in [Symfony issue 27477](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27477).

Is there a way to make the Symfony 4 FileType field show the selected filename when using Symfony's Bootstrap 4 theme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the Form file input field show the selected filename, [Bootstrap 4.3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#file-browser) recommends using the JavaScript library [bs-custom-file-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs-custom-file-input).

Add this JavaScript to your web page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs-custom-file-input/dist/bs-custom-file-input.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bsCustomFileInput.init()
    })
</script>
```